# Angular2 attribute directive: accessing parent or children element (queries?)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I would like to write an attribute directive applicable to `div`, which could access `div`'s children. I need it to rearrange children `span`s in response to parent (host) resizing.

I know of course that I could manipulate directly on `nativeElement` children, but it doesn't seem to be pretty. I tried @ViewChildren decorator, but no success in using it in directive.

So is there any other way except manipulating  `nativeElement`'s DOM?

Comment: Having the `span`s generated dynamically in the first place (by Angular) is not an option?

Comment: I'm designing responsive layout page, so I need to react and rearrange ``span``'s in reaction to page resize.

Comment: Sure. But instead of inserting some static markup inside a `<div>` and try to rearrange it *after the fact* (on page resize or whatever event), could you try to have Angular dynamically output this markup in the first place (based on page size or whichever criteria you want)?

Comment: Could you do it only with CSS?

Comment: @AngularFrance, user can resize window (ie. by rotating his tablet) anytime, so I need to do it _anytime_.

@Serginho, CSS media queries are not enough — user can resize parent ``div`` independly of browser window resize.

Comment: Yes, but Angular bindings are *live*. If your original markup is generated based on given criteria (e.g. page size or orientation), then the markup will automatically change when the criteria changes.